# Getting initramfs prompt with no error message Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

I turned on my computer this morning and it went straight to this initramfs prompt, no error messages, nothing. I tried reboot and it went to the grub menu. There were 5 selections of which I selected 2: Ubuntu with Linux 3.2.0-59-generic pae and then on the second attempt Ubuntu with Linux 3.2.0-59-generic pae (recovery mode). Both times I was brought back to the initramfs prompt. All of my masters thesis work is on this machine. Any help would be so greatly appreciated :/ I have been googling but can't seem to find an answer to why this is happening so I can't know how to ask to fix it...